# Typed param callback function in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, callback

I am trying to call a method that has a signature like this:

```
public final fun createMethod(
   methodParams: MethodParams,
   key: String?,
   accountId: String?,
   callback: ApiResultCallback<Method>
): Unit
```

I've tried to set this up using another function and the :: operator but can't get that to work. I would think that there would be a way to do this via lambda, but I've not gotten the proper incantation no matter what I try.

How can this be done please?

I would think it would be something like

```
classObject.createMethod(methodParamsObject, 
                        "NOT NEEDED", 
                        "123456789") { callback -> 
                          }
```

Comment: The only way to do this with lambdas is to _replace_ the type of `callback` with a function type.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
classObject.createMethod(methodParamsObject, 
                         "", 
                         "123456789",
                         object : ApiResultCallback<Method> {
                            override fun onSuccess(result: Method) {
                            }
                            override fun onError(e: Exception) {
                            }
                        })
                    }
```